# Motion in a plane due to a force

Tags: classical-mechanics

We know that a body moves in an unique plane under the action of a central force.
Is the motion of the body still in an unique plane if the central force is time dependent?

Also, I cannot think of a situation where the motion of a body due to a time independent force is NOT in a plane. So, does the body remain in a plane for any time independent force?

Answer (score 0):

The velocity $\vec v$ of the body and the direction of the force $\vec F$ define the plane of the motion. Since there will never be a component of the force outside of this plane, the body has to move within the plane. It is not important whether or not the force depends on time. E.g. if we think of an elliptic motion of a planet around the sun, and omit all the other planets, the force is not constant. Nevertheless, the motion is restricted to a plane. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Planar motion is a consequence of conservation of angular momentum. Central force has no torque with respect to the center and therefore angular momentum with respect to the center is conserved. So, if the force is always central with the same center, motion will be in one plane no matter if the force is time-dependent or not.

Regarding the second part of your question, one could imagine a force field which will lead to non-planar motion: just take some complicated electric field produced by several fixed changes not in the same plane and let a probe charge move in it.

Answer (score 0):

As is pointed out in other answers, a central force will always produce motion in a plane, regardless of whether the force is dependent on time or not. The key thing is that the force is always directed towards (or, possibly, directly away from) a fixed point.

On the other hand, a non-central force can produce non-planar motion even if it does not depend on time. For example, once you take into account the Earth's orbital motion, the orbit of the Moon does not lie in a fixed plane, which is why solar and lunar eclipses do not occur every month.